# What are full page reloads and Why did we need to do full page reloads without ajax?

Tags: ajax

I was reading up on ajax and how it empowers us to exchange data with a server behind the scenes and consequently avoid full page reloads. My confusion lies here, I don't really understand what full-page reloads mean. I think it's probably cause I've been working with ajax/react since the start I guess and have not really seen any webpage of mine fully reload when I access stuff from a database or an api.

It'd be great if someone could explain what they are and why did we need them before ajax?

Comment: F5 / Ctrl+R / Strg+R / Cmd+R / clicking on the reload icon in the top left of the browser window reloads the page.

Comment: Ohh gotcha but also why exactly did we need full reloads before ajax?

Comment: How do you get new / updated data on the client if you do not have Ajax? Right, via a page reload.

Comment: wait i took 5 mins to think of this but am still confused. What actually happens in a page reload? The browser rebuild the whole dom tree again? I think I'm mucky about this whole getting data and reloading thing. It'd be great if you could redirect me to some beginner level example where they did stuff w/o ajax. I have a feeling seeing an example will clear this confusion for me.

Comment: @jeremy The ajax is a javascript feature defined as `fetch` or `XHR` in the browser. To make it work for a specific site you need to download the content of that site and it will also load the ajax code in your browser for it. Then when you use the site it will give you the results from the backend without reloading whole page. Thus saves time. 

The google search suggestions comes from the ajax call when you start typing your keywords. To get that logic in your browser, you need to first request it via full page reload.

Comment: ooooh this makes sense. thanks for the example @tbhaxor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full page load is where the entire page is downloaded from the server. A page typically consists of several sections: header, footer, navigation, and content. In a classic web application without AJAX, a user clicks on a link to another page, and has to download the full page, even though only the main content is changing. The header, footer, and navigation all get downloaded again even though they don't change.

With AJAX there is the opportunity to only change the parts of the page that will change. When a user clicks on the link, JavaScript loads just the content for that link and inserts it into the current page. The header, footer, and navigation don't need to reload.

This introduces other problems that need attention.

- When AJAX inserts new content into the page, the URL doesn't change. That makes it difficult for users to bookmark or link to specific content. Well written AJAX applications use [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to update the URL when loading content via AJAX.
- There are then two paths to get to every piece of content. Users can either load the URL containing that content directly, or load the content into some other page by following a link. Web developers need to test and ensure both work.
- Search engines have trouble crawling AJAX powered sites. For best compatibility, you need to employ server side rendering (SSR) or pre-rendering to serve initial content on a page load that doesn't require JavaScript.

  Even for Googlebot (which executes JavaScript) care must be taken to make an AJAX powered site crawlable. Googlebot doesn't simulate user actions like clicking, scrolling, hovering, or moving the mouse.

  - Content needs to appear on page load without any user interaction
  - You must use `<a href=...>` links for navigation so that Googlebot can find other pages by scanning the document object model (DOM).  For users, JavaScript can intercept clicks on those links and prevent a full page load by using `return false` from the `onclick` handler or `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

Comment: it's all the more clear now for me. thanks a ton Stephen, especially for the extra bit on the possible red flags one might encounter when using Ajax as well!

Comment: i have a follow up doubt though, is react's state feature something based on ajax? I ask so because in react whenever there is a change in a state variable, the page updates content only for those variables w/o a full reload.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. You should probably ask it as a new question. I know that the link tag in react renders as an A tag with a href, so that part works fine. I'm not sure  how react handles State and URL changes.

Comment: @jeremy That is reactive programming (imo) not AJAX. Ajax is specifically with network requests like fetching data from some APIs and react state is simple sharable variable

Comment: just looked reactive programming up and yep it does makes sense. thanks @tbhaxor